# Doctrine 2 Index Inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm, indexing

i am new to Doctrine 2 am i trying to figure out how to do index inheritance with it.

What i am trying to achieve is to have a base class that defines some default columns along with necessary indexes for all entities within the application.

Example: All tables in my application will have `created_on` and `modified_on`, so i prepared one base `@MappedSuperclass` with those 2 columns in it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class EntityAbstract
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", name="created_on", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $createdOn;

    /**
     * @Column(type="datetime", name="modified_on", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $modifiedOn;

}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="member", indexes={@Index(name="credential", columns={"email_address", "password"})})
 */
class Member extends EntityAbstract
{
    /**
     * @Column(type="string", name="full_name", length=50)
     */
    protected $fullName;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", name="email_address", length=50, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $emailAddress;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", name="password", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $password;       

}
?>
```

I want to enforce `created_on` to be an index, so i put `@Index` annotation in the base class for this particular column. Hoping that this will result in 2 indexes for `Member` which is `created_on` and `email_address`+`password` combination. This however results in indexes of the base class being overriden by the child class, thus `created_on` is not an index.

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Table(indexes={@Index(name="timestampcreated", columns={"created_on"})})
 */
abstract class EntityAbstract
```

How do i achieve this in Doctrine 2? Have looked at single table inheritance, but my understanding is that it's meant for different purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a full solution for the way laid out at https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5928#issuecomment-273624392, thanks to https://medium.com/@alexkunin/doctrine-symfony-adding-indexes-to-fields-defined-in-traits-a8e480af66b2

```php
namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use App\Entity\Member;

class MemberIndexListener
{
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /** @var Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $classMetadata */
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        if (Member::class === $classMetadata->getName())
        {
            $prefix = strtolower((new \ReflectionClass($classMetadata->getName()))->getShortName()); // you can omit this line and ...
            $classMetadata->table['indexes'][$prefix.'_created_on'] =  // ... replace `[$prefix.'_created_on']` with `[]` for automatic index naming
                ['columns' => ['username']
            ];
            // For UniqueConstraints, use:
            // $classMetadata->table['uniqueConstraints'][...] = ...
        }
    }
}
```

And in `services.yaml`:

```
services:
    App\EventListener\MemberIndexListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, but `@Table` is not allowed in `@mappedSuperclass` classes. I've posted issue on doctrine2 github page https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5928 and the answer is:

> @Table is not valid on a mappedsuperclass.

When you think about it is sounds logical, but still, it would be nice if there is such functionality, to inherit indexes and other declarations.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution for automatic index inheritance.

You can specify indexes in table annotation of mapped superclass. And all children will extend them.

The listener takes indexes of all parent mapped superclases.

```
#src/EventListener/InheritIndexListener.php
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;

final class InheritIndexListener
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();
        $name = $classMetadata->name;

        if (!$classMetadata->isMappedSuperclass) {
            foreach (class_parents($name) as $parent) {
                $this->addParentIndexes($parent, $classMetadata);
            }
        }
    }

    private function addParentIndexes(string $parent, ClassMetadata $classMetadata): void
    {
        $parentMetadata = $this->entityManager
            ->getClassMetadata($parent);

        foreach ($parentMetadata->table['indexes'] as $index) {
            if (!$this->hasSameIndex($index, $classMetadata->table['indexes'])) {
                $classMetadata->table['indexes'][] = $index;
            }
        }

        foreach ($parentMetadata->table['uniqueConstraints'] as $uniqueConstraint) {
            if (!$this->hasSameIndex($uniqueConstraint, $classMetadata->table['uniqueConstraints'])) {
                $classMetadata->table['uniqueConstraints'][] = $uniqueConstraint;
            }
        }
    }

    private function hasSameIndex(array $needle, array $haystack): bool
    {
        foreach ($haystack as $item) {
            if ($item['columns'] === $needle['columns']) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}


#config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\InheritIndexListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

And entities.

```
#src/Entity/BaseResource.php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     indexes={
 *     @ORM\Index(columns={"external_id"}),
 *     }
 *     )
 */
abstract class BaseResource
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $externalId;
    //...
}

#src/Entity/BaseSlugableResource.php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Table
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"slug"}),
 *     },
 *     )
 */
abstract class BaseSlugableResource extends BaseResource
{
    /**
     * @var string|null
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $slug;
    //...
}

#src/Entity/Article.php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article extends BaseSlugableResource
{
    //...
}
```

In result the Article entity will have externalId index and slug unique index.

Comment: You need to explain what your solution consists of. Not just "here's some code" and paste it in the answer.